# Instalando plugins mediante vim-plug (Nvim)

Tags: plugin, vim, nvim

Mi vim-plug se carga correctamente con(como debe de ser)

> $ curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim

**La parte importante de mi init.vim:**
"Estos son mis plugins instalados y que funcionan(exepto Morhetz/gruvbox que es el que quiero agregar; pero no se intala cuando le doy a :PlugInstall en nvim)"

```js
call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/plugged')   "directorio donde se van a instalar los plugins

"plugins
plug 'Morhetz/gruvbox'              "Plugin agregado
Plug 'Yggdroot/indentLine'      "indentacion
Plug 'mattn/emmet-vim'          "emmet para diseño web
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'      "diseño de la barra en la cual se muestran los modos, la linea, etc.
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'   "temas para el vim-airline
Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'       "gestor de archivos en forma de arbol.
Plug 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'   "poder navegar entre archivos abiertos
Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'     "autocompletado de llaves, corchetes, etc.
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'} "autocompletado inteligente

call plug#end()             "cerramos el llamado de los plugins
```

E buscado mucho, pero no he dado con la solución, si alguien puede ayudarme, muchas gracias... ¿Cómo instalo un solo plugin con vin-plug en nvim?

Comment: Olvide mencionar que, no me sale ningún error solo es el echo que instala todos los plugin excepto 'Morhetz/gruvbox'..................

Answer (score 0):

Al fin pude resolverlo, tuve que borrar el contenido de la carpeta **plugged** donde se instalaron todos los plugins, luego también borre el contenido del archivo **init.vim**; y tuve que llenar de nuevo el init.vim incluyendo todos los nuevos plugins que queria instalar, y sus configuraciones.